# TypeError with function, but works fine otherwise

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers" with the following code below.

```
import json

j = {
    "id": 1000,
    "name": "John Doe"
}

def test(j):
    if j['id']:
        print("Value present")
    else:
        print("No Id found")

test(j)
```

Now run it:

```
python3 delme.py    
Value present
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delme.py", line 15, in <module>
    test("")
  File "delme.py", line 9, in test
    if j['id']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

But if I do the following, in a new Python instance, this evaluation works fine?

```
if j['id']
    print("WORKS")
```

What changes when passing j to a function?  Also, J will only ever have a single "id" key, so what is the simplest way to verify it's there or not?

Comment: The second code has a syntax error. And, afaik, that error can only happen when dealing with lists, and your code doesn't use any. Please show this as a proper [mcve]. There's no effective difference between the two that I can see with respect to that error. `j` must be becoming a list somewhere.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I revised code.

Comment: You're calling `test` with an empty string, not a dictionary.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I isolated this code.  This is all the code.

Comment: @Ethan if you try running just the code you posted, you will see that it runs fine. Your error is not from this code. It's clear because it points to line 15, but your code snippet only has 14 lines

Comment: Your error says you have `test("")`, not `test(j)`

Answer (score 2):

[The code you posted is fine](https://repl.it/repls/StrikingGainsboroCoordinate). The error you posted includes `test("")`, which is not the code you posted.

`j` is a parameter of `test` to the function so python is looking for a local variable in `test`. If you are trying to use the global then define test without an argument

```
j = {
    "id": 1000,
    "name": "John Doe"
}

def test(): # note: empty ()
    if j['id']:
        print("Value present")
    else:
        print("No Id found")

test() # added a call here
```

For code that **will reproduce the error** the global `j` is irrelevant:

```
def test(j):
    if j['id']:
        print("Value present")
    else:
        print("No Id found")

test("") # j will be ""
```